# Error: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' after ML deployment while testing through Postman

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Ahw.png)

We have deployed ML model to Azure Machine Learning workspace & getting endpoints. But while testing, we are getting the above error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is regarding the transformation you are performing in your modelling, you need to specify the X -> Independent variable which need to be transformed. In that transformation "X" is missing and place the accurate column index number of X need to be transformed and fit.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X)) # X is independent variable
```

something like above code block.